# What's the meaning of the slash in the end of disallow path?

Tags: url, path, seo, robots.txt, slash

Here are two lines in `robots.txt` file:

```
Disallow: /messages
Disallow: /qanda/edit/
```

What paths is this `/messages` point to? And what about `/qanda/edit/`? Is the `/` in the end of the second path useless? Or it has a specific meaning?

---

Or let me ask this way: what's the exact meaning of theses?

```
Disallow: /messages
Disallow: /messages/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Disallow` values represent the beginning of the URL path.

#### `Disallow: /messages`

would block URLs like these:

```
https://example.com/messages
https://example.com/messages.html
https://example.com/messages/
https://example.com/messages/foo
```

#### `Disallow: /messages/`

would block URLs like these:

```
https://example.com/messages/
https://example.com/messages/foo
```

but allow URLs like these:

```
https://example.com/messages
https://example.com/messages.html
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to disallow all in messages directory I think you have to let the slash at the end

```
Disallow: /messages/
```

if you dont put the "/" at the end, it could be /messages.html for exemple

```
Disallow : /messages
```

it is like

```
Disallow : /message*
```

Comment: you can find some details and exemple here : https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt